# UnicodeDecodeError - Add encoding to custom function input

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, encode

Could you tell me where I'm going wrong with my current way of thinking? This is my function:

```
def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):
  lines = open(f"realfolder/files/{item}.html", "r").readlines()
  lines[line_num] = text
  out = open(file_name, 'w')
  out.writelines(lines)
  out.close()
```

This is an example of it being called:

```
replace_line(f'./files/{item}.html', 9, f'text {item} wordswordswords' + '\n')
```

I need to encode the text input as utf-8. I'm not sure why I haven't been able to do this already. I also need to retain the fstring value.

I've been doing things like adding:

```
str.encode(text)
#or
text.encode(encoding = 'utf-8')
```

To the top of my replace line function. This hasn't worked. I have tried dozens of different methods but each continues to leave me with this error.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2982: character maps to
> undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the encoding to utf-8 for both opening the file to read from

```
lines = open(f"realfolder/files/{item}.html", "r", encoding="utf-8").readlines()
```

and opening the file to write to

```
out = open(file_name, 'w', encoding="utf-8")
```